# access spark via R locally or external

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

I have installed Spark under Windows and can run spark-shell and execute some Scala code in this shell (see also [here](https://dzone.com/articles/working-on-apache-spark-on-windows)). How can I now access this Spark environment externally via SparklyR or Python for example?

I ran:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

and can now access:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

However, if I run:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "http://localhost:8080/")
```

I get:

```
To run Spark on Windows you need a copy of Hadoop winutils.exe:

1. Download Hadoop winutils.exe from:

   https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/raw/master/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/

2. Copy winutils.exe to C:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\tmp\hadoop\bin

Alternatively, if you are using RStudio you can install the RStudio Preview Release,
which includes an embedded copy of Hadoop winutils.exe:

  https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/


Traceback:

1. spark_connect(master = "http://localhost:8080/")
2. shell_connection(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, app_name = app_name, 
 .     version = version, hadoop_version = hadoop_version, shell_args = shell_args, 
 .     config = config, service = spark_config_value(config, "sparklyr.gateway.service", 
 .         FALSE), remote = spark_config_value(config, "sparklyr.gateway.remote", 
 .         spark_master_is_yarn_cluster(master)), extensions = extensions)
3. prepare_windows_environment(spark_home, environment)
4. stop_with_winutils_error(hadoopBinPath)
5. stop("\n\n", "To run Spark on Windows you need a copy of Hadoop winutils.exe:", 
 .     "\n\n", "1. Download Hadoop winutils.exe from:", "\n\n", 
 .     paste("  ", winutilsDownload), "\n\n", paste("2. Copy winutils.exe to", 
 .         hadoopBinPath), "\n\n", "Alternatively, if you are using RStudio you can install the RStudio Preview Release,\n", 
 .     "which includes an embedded copy of Hadoop winutils.exe:\n\n", 
 .     "  https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/", 
 .     "\n\n", call. = FALSE)
```

I installed winutils.exe as part of my spark installation. How can I execute some basic hello world example (e.g. in R) against: http://localhost:8080/

PS:

I also tried to run:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://10.0.20.67:7077
spark-shell --master spark://10.0.20.67:7077
```

in succession.

Comment: The Spark web UI port isn't the Spark Master... It's not clear where you got `spark://10.0.20.67:7077`, but port 7077 might work better than 8080

Comment: thanks I got this from executing the stuff outlined in PS